# Execute jQuery in a 3rd party window (prototype)

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

This is my main question for ages and i never got a 100% answer (in some of the cases i managed to do what i want) and now i realize that i need a proper 100% answer to proceed.

I'm running Prototype-UI (Draggable windows and stuff) and i need to know how can i run jQuery scripts inside of these windows while fetching the content with Ajax.

Here is an example of what worked out for me:

```
             window.show_confirm = function(id) {
        var r = confirm("huhuhu");
        if (r == true) {
            jQuery.post('huhuhu.php', {'id':id}, function(data){});
              jQuery('#_'+id).animate({
        height: "0px",
        opacity: 0.0,
      }, 1500 );

        } else {
            alert("Item ["+id+"] was not deleted.");
        }

}
```

Here is an example of something that doesn't work:

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery(".line").peity("line");
});
```

Now the working example needs a click to run the function (this way users can only run it AFTER they opened the window).

In the second case this function needs to run from the moment the document is ready (basically when its executed there is still no DOM with `.line` class.)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you're asking, but from the last part I'm assuming it's how to call a jQuery function on is created that don't exist yet.

jQuery is an *imperative* library, not a *declarative* one – as a rule it only operates on currently existing elements (with the exception of "live" event handlers but that's not your use case). You need to make the call after the matching element is created somehow – either by doing the call after an AJAX request, or by using something like [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) to intercept DOM element creation.